# Rspec and gem errors despite having needed programs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems, rspec-rails

```
Unfortunately, an unexpected error occurred, and Bundler cannot continue.

First, try this link to see if there are any existing issue reports for this error:
https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/search?q=wrong+number+of+arguments+%28given+4%2C+expected+1%29&type=Issues

If there aren't any reports for this error yet, please fill in the new issue form located at https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/new?labels=Bundler&template=bundler-related-issue.md, and copy and paste the report template above in there.
```

I try to run  'bundle install' and I get this error. I am trying to run specs for a school project testing me on Ruby on Rails associations among other things. The project uses pSQL, Ruby and RoR. I am able to run 'bundle install &&  ./setup_db.sh' in the active_record_queries folder but not in the associations folder for that is where I receive the above comment. When I run just 'bundle install' I receive: Your RubyGems version (2.7.6)) has a bug that prevents `required_ruby_version` from working for Bundler. Any scripts that use `gem install bundler` will break as soon as Bundler drops support for your Ruby version. Please upgrade RubyGems to avoid future breakage and silence this warning by running `gem update --system 3.2.3`

I also need to run *./setup_db.sh* after as stated in the read me.
Why am I getting this error message?

```
/rails1_practice
├── README.md (<- you are here)
├── active_record_queries
|    └── README.md
├── associations
|    └── README.md
├── migrations
|    └── README.md
├── sql
|    └── README.md
```

> ace@ace-ThinkPad-T460:/$ rake about rake aborted! No Rakefile found
> (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
>
> ace@ace-ThinkPad-T460:/$ rake about rake aborted! No Rakefile found
> (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
>
> (See full trace by running task with --trace) ace@ace-ThinkPad-T460:/$
> rails -v Rails 7.0.2.2 ace@ace-ThinkPad-T460:/$ ruby -v ruby 3.1.1p18
> (2022-02-18 revision 53f5fc4236) [x86_64-linux]
> ace@ace-ThinkPad-T460:/$ rbenv -v rbenv 1.2.0-11-ge4f61e6
> ace@ace-ThinkPad-T460:/$ gem -v
> 3.3.7
> '''
> ace@ace-ThinkPad-T460:~/Desktop/codes/exactly!/rails1-practice/associations$ ./setup_db.sh
> Your RubyGems version (2.7.6)) has a bug that prevents `required_ruby_version` from working for Bundler. Any scripts that use `gem install bundler` will break as soon as Bundler drops support for your Ruby version. Please upgrade RubyGems to avoid future breakage and silence this warning by running `gem update --system 3.2.3`
> Could not find gem 'rails (>= 5.2.4.1, ~> 5.2.4)' in locally installed gems.
> Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
> Your RubyGems version (2.7.6)) has a bug that prevents `required_ruby_version` from working for Bundler. Any scripts that use `gem install bundler` will break as soon as Bundler drops support for your Ruby version. Please upgrade RubyGems to avoid future breakage and silence this warning by running `gem update --system 3.2.3`
> Could not find gem 'rails (>= 5.2.4.1, ~> 5.2.4)' in locally installed gems.
> Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
> Your RubyGems version (2.7.6)) has a bug that prevents `required_ruby_version` from working for Bundler. Any scripts that use `gem install bundler` will break as soon as Bundler drops support for your Ruby version. Please upgrade RubyGems to avoid future breakage and silence this warning by running `gem update --system 3.2.3`
> Could not find gem 'rails (>= 5.2.4.1, ~> 5.2.4)' in locally installed gems.
> Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
> Your RubyGems version (2.7.6)) has a bug that prevents `required_ruby_version` from working for Bundler. Any scripts that use `gem install bundler` will break as soon as Bundler drops support for your Ruby version. Please upgrade RubyGems to avoid future breakage and silence this warning by running `gem update --system 3.2.3`
> Could not find gem 'rails (>= 5.2.4.1, ~> 5.2.4)' in locally installed gems.
> Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
> Your RubyGems version (2.7.6)) has a bug that prevents `required_ruby_version` from working for Bundler. Any scripts that use `gem install bundler` will break as soon as Bundler drops support for your Ruby version. Please upgrade RubyGems to avoid future breakage and silence this warning by running `gem update --system 3.2.3`
> Could not find gem 'rails (>= 5.2.4.1, ~> 5.2.4)' in locally installed gems.
> Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
> Your RubyGems version (2.7.6)) has a bug that prevents `required_ruby_version` from working for Bundler. Any scripts that use `gem install bundler` will break as soon as Bundler drops support for your Ruby version. Please upgrade RubyGems to avoid future breakage and silence this warning by running `gem update --system 3.2.3`
> Could not find gem 'rails (>= 5.2.4.1, ~> 5.2.4)' in locally installed gems.
> Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
> Your RubyGems version (2.7.6)) has a bug that prevents `required_ruby_version` from working for Bundler. Any scripts that use `gem install bundler` will break as soon as Bundler drops support for your Ruby version. Please upgrade RubyGems to avoid future breakage and silence this warning by running `gem update --system 3.2.3`
> Could not find gem 'rails (>= 5.2.4.1, ~> 5.2.4)' in locally installed gems.
> Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
> ace@ace-ThinkPad-T460:~/Desktop/codes/exactly!/rails1-practice/associations$ gem update --systemn 3.2.3
> Failed to load /home/ace/.gemrc, wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
> invalid option: --systemn
> ace@ace-ThinkPad-T460:~/Desktop/codes/exactly!/rails1-practice/associations$ gem update system
> Failed to load /home/ace/.gemrc, wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
> Updating installed gems
> Nothing to update
> '''

Comment: ace@ace-ThinkPad-T460:/$ rails -v
Rails 7.0.2.2